# Calling nodejs scripts from the command line does not work

Tags: node.js

This is what my file test.js contains:

```
console.log("Hello Stackoverflow");
```

This is what happens when I attempt to run it:

```
$ ls
test.js
$ node test.js
$ node test
$ node "test"
$ node "test.js"
$ node --debug test.js
debugger listening on port 5858
$ node --debug test
debugger listening on port 5858
$
```

Notice that it never works :( I can run just "node" and evaluate javascript statements line by line but whenever I try to run a script as above it does not work.

I'm running OS X 10.8 and a brand new installation of nodejs.

Comment: I'm not on a Mac, but I'm unable to reproduce this (Win 7 x64, node v0.10.16).

Comment: Odd.. it works just fine over here

Comment: It's very odd that `node test` doesn't return an error. Perhaps `node` is aliased to something.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution to my problem was to uninstall node using:

```
sudo rm -rf /usr/local/{bin/{node,npm},lib/node_modules/npm,lib/node,share/man/*/node.*}
```

I then installed brew on my mac:

```
ruby -e "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.github.com/mxcl/homebrew/go)"
```

And then I did

```
brew doctor
```

I fixed the issues it told me to fix from that, and then I did

```
brew install node
```

I then restarted terminal, and node was working.